# Can mobs activate pressure plates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have one pressure plate on each side of my door to get in and out of my house quickly, and if mobs can activate pressure plates, then I'm most likely doomed.

Comment: Try a stone button next to your door instead!

Comment: Yeah, a stone button next to the door works great because you don't even need to wire it using redstone, assuming you place it adjacent to the door.

Comment: pressure plates also don't need redstone to open a door...

Comment: It's worth mentioning the Mincraft mod [Better Tthan Wolves](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndVVrZqHqA8), which adds an obsidian pressure plate that is only triggered by players, not monsters.

Comment: @JonathanDrain [Obsidian Pressure Plates](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/obsidian-pressure-plates.755/) has since been recreated as a standalone mod.

Comment: If you're using mods, I can highly recommend [Malisis Doors](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2076338-malisisdoors-1-7-10-1-4-3-23-01-2015). It adds sensors that you place over your doors (like at the supermarket), allowing doors to open automatically when a player (not mob) is close by. It also add a smooth door opening animation, lots of new types of doors, and just generally improves door mechanics.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, they can, which makes them fun to set up traps. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pressure_Plate)

Answer (score 10):

Yes they can!

I suggest that you use a button for the outside and a pressure plate on the inside, or if you use a wooden door, just use a pressure plate on the inside as you can just click on it to open, and as you go in, the pressure plate closes it.  For going outside, it closes itself.

Answer (score 8):

Yes they can indeed, however with some clever usage of redstone wires you can make a switch function as a lock on the door, so you can have it react to the plates when you're working around the house and lock it up at night or when going roaming.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah they can. I use a button now because mobs can't use them.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably get those changed out for safety reasons. According to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pressure_Plate) mobs can currently activate pressure plates.

Answer (score 3):

Using a lever positioned above the door works better for me. I always have trouble getting through the door before it closes.

If you leave the block above the door empty, and place a simple lever on the block above the empty block, the program considers the lever to be adjacent to the door and it can be used from the inside or the out.

Answer (score 1):

***Yes they can!***

I was having the same question and turns out they can. Maybe use a lever or a button instead, but I personally find the pressure plate the easiest to use. There is a mod called [Minecraft Detector Pressure Plate Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/831849-minecraft-detector-pressure-plate-mod-100/), which allows you to choose what can activate it. This mod won't work without [ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v100-risugamis-mods-everything-updated/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course they can. The only difference between stone and wood pressure plates is that the wooden ones can be opened by dropping a item on them while the other one can not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currently they can, but what I have done is rigged a trapdoor to the pressure plate controlled by a switch. When you turn the switch on the plate controls the door. When the switch is off, though, it controls the trap designed to combat mobs. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, they can. If you really want pressure plates without mobs coming in, maybe try one on the inside, but not the outside. On the outside, try putting a button. If you do, you will be able to quickly go *outside*, but not inside, but mobs will not be able to get in unless you let them.

Comment: this adds nothing to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/33285/87186) answer.

Answer (score 0):

They can. However, they can't activate heavy pressure plates.